# Using Fisher LDA in R

Tags: machine-learning, discriminant-analysis

I have run a large study looking at traumatic brain injury in patients I have conducted CT scans on patients very soon after the injury as well as neurocognitive testing and then repeated this at 1 year post-injury. At 1 year, I have also classified patients into "good" and "bad" outcomes based on their functional status. I also have control data.

I'd like to use a Fisher LDA to try and "predict" which patients will end up with bad outcomes from the initial CT scan / neurocognitive datasets.

What is the best way to go about this? That is, in an ideal world, would have two large data sets so could "train" on one and then run the prediction on the other

Is it OK to run the training on the 1 year outcome data and then apply this training to the data from the time of injury?

Comment: How many patients do you have in a 'large' study? You might want to use something more flexible such as a neural network instead of LDA. I imagine that there can be effects that are not uniform among different patients and if the patterns do not always occur in the same spot on the scan then the LDA will only see it as a blurry pattern instead of a sharp point.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have data about each patients in both datasets I suggest taking only CT scans and neurocognitive test results from the time that occured *soon after the injury*, and the final status of the patient *after one year*. Then you can apply other techniques (such as CV or boot-strapping) to evalutate the classifiers performance.

Comment: Thanks. I have data from both time points. I am trying to use R to do this. Could you go into more detail for me? How should I run the classifier?

Comment: I recommed a `caret` package. Check [this](http://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html) for a lot of useful examples.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it OK to run the training on the 1 year outcome data and then apply this training to the data from the time of injury?

Your training is supposed to learn to recognise  and predict bad outcomes based on CT scans.

For this purpose it seems to me like you have a model that takes the CT scans soon after injury as input and predict the classification of 'good'/'bad' based on that. So train the model with those inputs and outputs.

The application of the model is in *new* data of the *same* type. So again on CT scans from soon after the injury.

And you can test how well the model does this by splitting your data into multiple groups, one part to train the model, another part to test the model, and possibly a data set to select the best model if you have tuning parameters. You can look for the term [cross validation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) to learn more about this.